# Unable to load jar using dbms_java.loadjava in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, user-defined-functions, oracle12c, loadjava

I need to upload a jar file in Oracle RDBMS using `dbms_java.loadjava` method. I have granted all the required permission and able to run below function successfully.

```
create or replace function get_java_property(prop in varchar2)
return varchar2 is
language java name 'java.lang.System.getProperty(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';

select get_java_property('java.version') from dual;

1.8.0_231
```

However, I also need to upload an external jar and use the same. I am successfully able to do the same by placing jar on Oracle Server and running `loadjava` command. However I want to do the same using `dbms_java.loadjava` from my local system. I am trying following query.

```
call dbms_java.loadjava('–proxy -Dhttp.proxyHost=my_local_system_ip -Dhttp.proxyPort=22 file:///home/Documents/abc.jar');
```

Its returning `Call completed.` However, jar is not uploaded as I have tried to access methods in Jar and getting error

```
ORA-29540: class com/pkg_name/function_name does not exist
29540. 00000 -  "class %s does not exist"  
*Cause:    Java method execution failed to find a class with the indicated name.
*Action:   Correct the name or add the missing Java class.
```

However same methods are accessible when jar is uploaded through `loadjava` command. Please suggest. May be I am missing some basics.

Answer (score 1):

When loading from a local file you don't have to use the -proxy switch:

`call dbms_java.loadjava('//home/Documents/abc.jar');`

Note: The path must reside on the database server machine